# Webpack compilation error with Cypress-webpack-preprocessor

Tags: npm, webpack, cypress

I am not able to run cypress test and getting foll error:

When I ran cypress run:

It is giving below Webpack compilation error

```
Webpack Compilation Error
./cypress/integration/features/Pagination.feature
 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 
'C:UsersCypressProjectode_modulescypress-cucumber-preprocessorlibesolveStepDefinition' in 'C:\Users\CypressProject\cypress\integration\features'
```

**Somehow backslashes are also not included in above path**

My webpack config file is as :

```
module.exports = {
resolve: {
  extensions: [".ts", ".js"]
},

node: { fs: "empty", child_process: "empty", readline: "empty" },
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.ts$/,
      exclude: [/node_modules/],
      use: [
        {
          loader: "ts-loader"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      test: /\.feature$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/loader"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
};
```

My plugin file:

```
const wp = require('@cypress/webpack-preprocessor')

const fs = require('fs-extra')
const path = require('path')

function getConfigurationByFile (file) {
  const pathToConfigFile = path.resolve('./cypress/', 'config', `${file}.json`)
  return fs.readJson(pathToConfigFile)
}

module.exports = (on,config) => {
    const file = process.env.ENV_FILE//config.env.envFile
  const options = {     
    webpackOptions: require("../webpack.config.js")
  };
  on('file:preprocessor', wp(options))
  if(file==null){
  return getConfigurationByFile('local');
  }
  else{
    return getConfigurationByFile(file);
  }
}
```

Anybody having idea to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

You should set your `step_definition` path inside `package.json` with

```
"cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "step_definitions": "path/to/steps_definition"
}
```

Comment: Still I get the issue like ./cypress/support/step_definitions/steps.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/cypress/index.js):
LoaderRunnerError: Module 'C:\Users\ui\node_modules\cypress\index.js' is not a loader (must have normal or pitch function)
 @ ./cypress/integration/features/TC_170.feature 37:0-157
 @ multi ./cypress/integration/features/TC_170.feature